# Using webworkers in typescript Excel add-in

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, web-worker

I have an add-in (built with officejs) which downloads, processes and puts large data arrays to Excel. The problem is when the processing takes too long Excel kills the add-in immediately. I tried to delegate all the work to a webworker in order to make the UI perform only the work of a messenger. The problem is that I can't call Office.initialize in a webworker (I understand that a webworker has its own scope, etc.). My question is - is it possible to make calls to Excel from the webworker and if so - how to make them correctly?

Edit: Here's example source:

app.js

```
function createTableWorker() {
    if (typeof(worker) == "undefined"){
        console.log("creating new worker!");
        worker = new Worker("test_worker.js");
    }

    worker.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log("From worker: " + event.data);
    };

    worker.postMessage("message");
}
```

worker.js

```
this.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Worker On Message!");
    importScripts("https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.debug.js");
    doExcelWork();
}

function doExcelWork() {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        debugger;
        const currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        const expensesTable = currentWorksheet.tables.add("A1:D1", true /*hasHeaders*/);
        expensesTable.name = "ExpensesTable";

        expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = 
        [["Date", "Merchant", "Category", "Amount"]];

        expensesTable.rows.add(null /*add at the end*/, [
        ["1/1/2017", "The Phone Company", "Communications", "120"],
        ["1/2/2017", "Northwind Electric Cars", "Transportation", "142.33"],
        ["1/5/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "27.9"],
        ["1/10/2017", "Coho Vineyard", "Restaurant", "33"],
        ["1/11/2017", "Bellows College", "Education", "350.1"],
        ["1/15/2017", "Trey Research", "Other", "135"],
        ["1/15/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "97.88"]
        ]);

        expensesTable.columns.getItemAt(3).getRange().numberFormat = [['€#,##0.00']];
        expensesTable.getRange().format.autofitColumns();
        expensesTable.getRange().format.autofitRows();

        return context.sync();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });

    postMessage("Hello World Msg!");
}
```

The example was made by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial and moving the Excel.run to a webworker.

Comment: Can you show some code, enough to make [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current design won't work. `Excel.run()` has to be in a context where Office.initialize has been called. As I understand it, you had a version that worked provided the input size was small enough. Would it be possible for you to batch the input so that each batch is processed with it's own `Excel.run()`? And then the next batch is handled by a new call of method that calls `Excel.run()`.